# Minecraft Server - Performance issues due to CPU?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hardware

Im running a Minecraft Server and somehow it is struggling with timing. - So its laggy, sometimes more, sometimes less.
So I probably figured out that this is a problem caused by my CPU, since its running on 2,7GHz.
(Also the RAM is on 48GB and never used more than 40%).
As far as I know I have 8 cores, and im sure Minecraft uses just one..
So is there any Option - maybe in the start script - to use more cores, so I can run a more stable Server?

The Server runs on a Debian10 vServer.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft servers currently only run off of one thread; every instruction is ran in sequence very quickly, rather than at the same time.

There's an experimental Forge mod that does allow for some multithreading called [MCMT](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/mcmt-multithreading) (specifically the multithreading of ticks), but it's relatively unstable and might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Almost correct - Minecraft defers lighting and some other non-time-critical tasks to a separate thread, but it's true the bulk of the processing is single-thread and as such, single-CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The things I can list off of my head could be that:

1. You have somehow set up the server wrong
2. You have to many players on your server
3. You have to many plugins or a world gen plugin
4. A mod might not be compatible with another and is lagging the server

That's all I can think of, please tell me what other things the server has on it so I can better assist the situation (ex: plugins, mods, players, hosting).

Comment: Im not 100% sure, but im pretty sure that the setup is fine.
the lags start even if there are only 5 player.
round about 35  Plugins, but the timings output didn't show any issues with those.

Comment: Well then I don't understand how there could be an issue.